# find category from reference values put in columns in R

Tags: r

I have following data and code:

```
> dput(mydata)
structure(list(P3 = c(99.4, 105.8, 111.9), P5 = c(100.4, 106.9, 
113.1), P10 = c(102, 108.6, 114.9), P25 = c(104.8, 111.6, 118.1
), P50 = c(108, 115, 121.8), P75 = c(111.2, 118.6, 125.6), P90 = c(114.3, 
121.9, 129.1), P95 = c(116.1, 123.9, 131.3), P97 = c(117.4, 125.3, 
132.7), val = c(115.5, 112.7, 117)), .Names = c("P3", "P5", "P10", 
"P25", "P50", "P75", "P90", "P95", "P97", "val"), row.names = 7:9, class = "data.frame")
> 
> mydata
     P3    P5   P10   P25   P50   P75   P90   P95   P97   val
7  99.4 100.4 102.0 104.8 108.0 111.2 114.3 116.1 117.4 115.5
8 105.8 106.9 108.6 111.6 115.0 118.6 121.9 123.9 125.3 112.7
9 111.9 113.1 114.9 118.1 121.8 125.6 129.1 131.3 132.7 117.0
```

I want to create a new column 'categ' in mydata which will have the 'number' part of the name of first column (checked from left to right) which contains value larger than 'val' of that row.

Hence, I should get 95,50,25 in the new column.

I know of 'findInterval' and 'match' functions that are used for this kind of classification but I am not able to apply them to mydata. Thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI, `dput(mydata)` and the shown data don't match

Comment: My fault.I had adjusted one value in table which I forgot to change in dput. I have corrected the error now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
indx <- max.col(mydata[,-10] >mydata$val,'first')
mydata$categ <- as.numeric(sub("[A-Z]+", "", names(mydata)[indx]))
mydata$categ
#[1] 95 50 25
```

Or

```
indx <- apply(mydata[,-10] > mydata$val, 1, function(x) names(which(x))[1])
```

and then use `sub` as before

#### data

```
mydata <- structure(list(P3 = c(99.4, 105.8, 111.9), P5 = c(100.4, 106.9, 
113.1), P10 = c(102, 108.6, 114.9), P25 = c(104.8, 111.6, 118.1
), P50 = c(108, 115, 121.8), P75 = c(111.2, 118.6, 125.6), P90 = c(114.3, 
121.9, 129.1), P95 = c(116.1, 123.9, 131.3), P97 = c(117.4, 125.3, 
132.7), val = c(115.5, 112.7, 117)), .Names = c("P3", "P5", "P10", 
"P25", "P50", "P75", "P90", "P95", "P97", "val"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c("7", "8", "9"))
```

Comment: I especially like the second solution which uses apply function.

Comment: @rnso The first one may be faster (not benchmarked)

Comment: The first one seems to be vectorized, so I would go with it

Comment: @DavidArenburg yep, see my time-test.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the post-question about speed:

```
bigdat<-mydata
for(j in 1:10) bigdat<- rbind(bigdat,bigdat)
frist<-function(mydata) {
    indx <- max.col(mydata[,-10] >mydata$val,'first')
mydata$categ <- as.numeric(sub("[A-Z]+", "", names(mydata)[indx]))
}

sceond <- function(mydata) indx <- apply(mydata[,-10] > mydata$val, 1, function(x) names(which(x))[1]) 
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(frist(bigdat),sceond(bigdat))

Unit: milliseconds
           expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
  frist(bigdat)  5.400829  5.688074  7.166702  7.816168 142.6927   100
 sceond(bigdat) 22.333659 24.442536 25.422791 26.984677 178.7408   100
```

EDIT: per akrun's comment, I added the same regex line to the `sceond` function, but it dosn't affect the timing:

```
sceond <- function(mydata) {
    indx <- apply(mydata[,-10] > mydata$val, 1, function(x) names(which(x))[1]) 
    mydata$categ <- as.numeric(sub("[A-Z]+", "", names(mydata)[indx]))
    }
Unit: milliseconds
           expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
  frist(bigdat)  5.315901  5.613826  6.940932  7.791208  29.15699   100
 sceond(bigdat) 22.359897 24.588688 25.636795 27.868710 359.79325   100
```